# Exporting C++ code from an R package with Rcpp::interfaces(r, cpp) throws error `PACKAGE_RcppExport_registerCCallable" not available for .Call()`

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package

I'm trying to export C++ functions from my R package '[TreeTools](https://www.github.com/ms609/TreeTools)' so they can be called from a different package.  I've added the line

```
// [[Rcpp::interfaces(r, cpp)]]
```

to `src/renumber_tree.cpp`, per [https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-attributes.pdf / http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html] and when I `compileAttributes()` and `document()` the package, there are indicators that the export has been acknowledged:

- Relevant header files are added to `inst/includes`;
- `#include "../inst/include/TreeTools.h"` is added to the start of `RcppExports.cpp`
- A function `RcppExport SEXP _TreeTools_RcppExport_registerCCallable()` is added to the end of `RcppExports.cpp`

Compliation nevertheless fails with

```
Error in .Call("_TreeTools_RcppExport_registerCCallable", PACKAGE = "TreeTools") : 
  "_TreeTools_RcppExport_registerCCallable" not available for .Call() for package "TreeTools"
```

Can anyone help me to debug this error?
Could it be related to the fact that I have a manually-generated `PACKAGE-init.c` file?

Comment: Ensure you run `compileAttributes()` when you (re-)define interface. I was just using this on a package the other day and corresponding glue _is_ generated.  Make sure all files are updated, what you show leads me to suspect one was left behind.

Comment: And of course double-check that the symbols requested are present, including in the "setup" bits typically at the bottom of `src/RcppExports.cpp`.  Also, and this may sound like extra work, maybe test the basic functionality on a one-function ad-hoc package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Dirk, for pointing me in the right direction.

To `TreeTools-init.C`, I needed to add

```c
extern SEXP _TreeTools_RcppExport_registerCCallable();
```

and

```c
static const R_CallMethodDef callMethods[] = {
  &_TreeTools_RcppExport_registerCCallable, 0},
  {NULL, NULL, 0}
};
```

In `RcppExports.R`, I saw

```r
# Register entry points for exported C++ functions
methods::setLoadAction(function(ns) {
    .Call('_TreeTools_RcppExport_registerCCallable', PACKAGE = 'TreeTools')
})
```

Replacing the straight quotes around '_TreeTools_RcppExport_registerCCallable' with backticks, i.e.

```r
`_TreeTools_RcppExport_registerCCallable`
```

allowed the package to load.

Of course, these are replaced with straight quotes whenever `compileAttributes()` is run, so this doesn't feel like a complete solution...

Comment: I fear you may only be giving us a half-picture because `compileAttributes()` writes what we otherwise manually put into an `init*.c(pp)` file for us too, unless one is found.  Maybe try a simpler example of one function, nothing else, and see if you get both interfaces registered automatically. In other words, you could try removing `src/TreeTools-init.c` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I've deleted `src/TreeTools-init.c`, but `compileAttributes()` does not re-create it.  If I delete the definition of `R_CallMethodDef callMethods` and `R_init_TreeTools` from `TreeTools-init.c`, then these functions are added to `RcppExports.cpp` -- but `cMethods[]` is not passed to `R_registerRoutines`.

Comment: Right, it would not re-create the file (but its content) as part of RcppExports.cpp.  I was just exploring use of these registration methods myself in another package (and ended up doing it by hand) so I think some (generated) code also ends in `inst/include`.  Maybe the best move forward would be, if you could, a minimal one function package, showing what you try and see where it fails leading to an issue ticket.   Someone seems to entangle it here in your package which is frustrating.  (But there are a few Rcpp-using packages "exporting", maybe most "by hand"....)

Comment: I've created a one-function package and created a ticket at https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/1110. Thanks for your help here.